# Enforce no space after annotation and before its elements in Java

Tags: java, checkstyle

I want to have unified way of declaring annotations in my Java project for annoations usage.

I'd like to prohibit any whitespace after annoation name and before its parentheses with it's elements:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") void run1() {} // OK

@SuppressWarnings         ("unchecked") void run2() {} // Warn!

@Override void run3() {} // OK

@SuppressWarnings ( // Warn!
    value = "unchecked"
)
void run4() {}
```

Is there any Checkstyle check to help me with that? I haven't found anything that is ready to be used.

Comment: You should also be able to configure a profile for your IDE to format these the way you like, and have it run automatically on save. If that doesn't catch everything, it's also possible to apply formatting across a project - you could that periodically to enforce the standard (rather than breaking your pipeline).

Comment: @JohnMcClean, that's also an option, but then "reformatting commits" are polluting history of changes in files. Whoever will get broken pipeline with such violation can fix their IDE config to do it properly from this point of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkstyle does not offer such a rule for annotations but it is [easy enough to write your own rule](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingchecks.html). The rules that checkstyle does offer out-of-the-box only include rules that are [applied to any code element](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/checks.html), e.g. rules to not have white-space after an annotation (or anything else).

Comment: Are you sure that no existing rule can be configured to satisfy my requirement? If yes, then I'm going to write my own one.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, no, there is no such rule.

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ IDEA's *Simplifiable annotation* inspection warns about this issue.